# Keystone errors on forked repo

Tags: git, github, cloudinary, keystonejs

I'm working on a Keystone based project with a friend of mine. He has done all of the initializing on his end and pushed everything to GitHub. I have forked and cloned down the repo to my machine (macOS 10.13).

When attempting to run `node keystone` I get this:

```
Error: Invalid Configuration

CloudinaryImage fields (About.heroImage) require the "cloudinary 
config" option to be set.

See http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#services-cloudinary for 
more information.
```

I don't see any .env file so I can get everything authenticated on my machine to run Keystone.

Why would his .env file not be pushed on to GitHub? Or is my issue something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing .env is needed for all scenario.
You can create your own .env file like this

```
CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://252283466736269:-RpHzXCFeqKuN1dqwO11P68pNN4s@enraiser
```

Answer (score 0):

`.env` files should never ever ever be committed to git, since they probably contain secret info and environment specific configuration.

An `.env` file simply contains key/value pairs, so all you need to do is create a file in the root of the project called `.env` and add the required values.

If you use https://github.com/keystonejs/generator-keystone it will create a sample env file for you. But obviously it could be that your friend's project has some specific required configuration options, you'll need to ask him.